# Regular Expression statement to replace text inside two literals

Tags: regex, editplus

i have n line of code starting with

```
(21714,
(21715,
```

I want to replace the numeric values with NULL string to get

```
(NULL,
(NULL,
```

Please suggest the reqular expression I should use in Edit plus Find Replace functionality to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

It may looks like this (this example is written in js, but I don't think it is a problem):

```
'(21714, (21715, ...'.replace(/^(\([0-9]*\,\s\([0-9]*)/, "(NULL, (NULL");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested these steps via EditPlus v3.41:

step1. Menu > Search > Replace

step2. click "More" button

step3. input pattern `\([0-9]+,` to "Find what"

step4. Replace with `(NULL,`

Answer (score 0):

^([0-9]*

I used this, it searched for occurrences:
(21714
(21715